# get date as integer from createdAt field of mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have users collection in mongoDB and timestamp is on.
so users have createdAt field.
i want to retrieve array of dates from users collection's createdAt field.
i want to get data in this format: [ 12, 12,13 , 14, 15, 17]

Comment: Have a look at [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/#datetoparts-aggregation)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
let dates = await db.users.aggregate([
   { $group : {
    _id: {
        year : { $year : "$createdAt" },        
        month : { $month : "$createdAt" },        
        day : { $dayOfMonth : "$createdAt" },
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
     }
   }
])
```

It gives you created dates and the number of subscribed users on these days.